# What are the current open source text-to-audio libraries?

Tags: audio-processing

I am not new to AI and did some work for few months but completely new to text to audio. Yes I used text to audio tools a decade back... but I would like to know where exactly we stand in terms of text to audio today.

I already did some research, it seems like traditional way of text to audio is fading away and speech cloning seems to be emerging but my impression on this might be completely wrong.

What are the current open source text-to-audio libraries?

Answer (score 1):

[**voice-builder**](https://github.com/google/voice-builder) is an opensource text-to-speech (TTS) voice building tool from Google.

Answer (score 0):

There is one by Mozilla called Deep Voice 
And another python library called pocket-sphinx